# Linq Query, looping thru datatable, joining and get the index

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query where I have two datatables that I am joining together and looping thru using a `.foreach` and the manipulating data in the the `foreach`. How do I get the row index of the row while I am looping thru in the foreach?

I know how to do it with out the join in it and the easy way is just to put a int variable before the linq statement and increment in the foreach., but wanted to know if I can add the `.Select(Row,index) => new {row,index})` in this query

```
 Datatable1.AsEnumerable()
             .Join(Datatable2.AsEnumerable(),
                 dt1row => dt1row.Field<string>("name"),
                 dt2row => dt2row.Field<string>("name")) ,
                 (dt1row, dt2row) => new { dt1row, dt2row }).ToList()
             .ForEach(o =>
             {
                 //check if value for fields is the same in 


             });
```

Comment: As powerful as LINQ is, that code simply does my head in! lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
 Datatable1.AsEnumerable()
           .Join(Datatable2.AsEnumerable(),
                 dt1row => dt1row.Field<string>("name"),
                 dt2row => dt2row.Field<string>("name")) ,
                 (dt1row, dt2row) => new { dt1row, dt2row })
           .Select((row, index)=> new 
                  {
                      Index=index, 
                      Dt1row = row.dt1row, 
                      Dt2row = row.dt2row
                  }).ToList()
                    .ForEach(o =>
                    {
                        //check if value for fields is the same in 
                    });
```

Comment: Why would he need a ToList() ?

Comment: He needs `ToList()`, because the `ForEach()` is a method of `List`. You can't call it on the result of a linq query, which usually is a `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Then he should ,  write his own ForEach

     public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)

And Call ToList() after , though it's pretty much the same thing in this case ( there might be some performance benefit or concatenating the Linq Expression and still working against an IEnumrable. 
        {
            foreach (T element in source)
            {
                action(element);
            }

            return source;
        }

Comment: @eranotzap I agree with you dude. That's an option. It's up to the OP what he will pick up as a solution to the problem he stated. You approach sounds reasonbale to me. However I think that the apporach in my post is a bit simpler in it's implementation.